# Numbering print statements in python

Tags: python, printing

I've been looking around but couldn't find a solution to this problem,
~ this doesn't require any coding for the actual problem!~

If i'm given a file and I print out each line using the for...open(filename).
This would give me a result of...

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line....
```

However, what I'm trying to do is number each line so that my print should look like...

```
#1 line 1
#2 line 2
#3 line 3
```

How would I go about altering my print statement to print out #1-30 for each line counting up.

Comment: This is a recurring motif in python - how do I get the index I'm on while I iterate over a thing?  The answer tends to be `enumerate`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) in loops to generate numbers:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        print('#{}: {}'.format(i, line.rstrip('\n'))
```

The `1` start value instructs `enumerate()` to start at 1 instead of the default 0.

Comment: Instead of taking off the `\n` - I'd be tempted to not add it on  using `end=''` instead

Comment: I was wondering why I can't iterate bools?  For instance, lets say my list was created in the main function. Then I created another function which divides that list into 2 lists and sorts each of those two lists independently. Then I print out the top 20 from each of those 2 lists separately. Why wouldn't I be able to have a count in the for loop to iterate a count in the print statement?

Comment: None of that involves booleans. You cannot iterate over booleans because a `True` or `False` value is not a sequence or iterable; there is no *series* of values, just *one* value. If you have an error involving `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable` then you did something wrong and your code is not doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
import sys

with open(filename) as f:
    lines = ('#{} {}'.format(lineno, line) for lineno, line in enumerate(f, 1))
    sys.stdout.writelines(lines)
```